# Total participation in Dia

Tags: entity-relationship, dia

I have just started to use Dia for designing ER diagrams and I cannot seem to find a way to show total participation, which is usually expressed by a double line. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add new shapes to the software, but you to create them first.. I've just done an example for you (it's in Spanish but I think you'll understand):

1. Create the new shape in dia

[image]

2. Export to a shape format

[image]

3. Select File → Sheets and Objects from the menu to open the Sheets and Objects dialog or press F9.

[image]

4. Sheets and Objects dialog. Click on the New button - a new dialog will be opened

[image]

5. Select your new shape and then click on Acept

[image]
[image]

6. You'll see your new shape like this:

[image]

7. Add it wherever you want

[image]

You can check this [manual](http://dia-installer.de/howto/create_shape/index.html.en).

Hope you find this useful!

Answer (score 2):

Just double click on the line you want to represent double participation and switch Total to Yes:

[image]

However, note that the line must have been created using the Participation symbol of the ER sheet.